# Traçar um gráfico do carregamento e da descarga de um capacitor no MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, equações

Preciso criar um programa que mostra através do plot a carga e a descarga de um capacitor conforme imagens abaixo:

[image: carga]
[image: descarga]

São 3 constantes onde o usuário precisa informar os valores:
C = capacitância;
R = resistência
E = tensão da fonte (exemplo; uma fonte de 20v);

Consegui fazer o gráfico de carga através desse código:

[image: soluçao]

Comment: O que já tentastes?

Comment: Ainda não comecei Renan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso pretenda fazer o gráfico teórico basta continuar da mesma forma que começou, pedindo os valores e mostrando a figura para um e outro caso. Pode mostrar o resultado na mesma figura ou figuras separadas.
Recomendo usar um tempo t dependente do valor de Tau. Um condensador carrega/descarrega totalmente em 5*Tau, por isso o codigo seguinte mostra figuras sempre ajustadas ao valor de Tau.

```
C = input ('Digite o valor do condensador (em uF): ')
R = input ('Digite o valor da resistencia (em Ohms): ')
E = input ('Digite o valor da fonte de tensao (em V): ')

C = 10^-6
Tau = R * C;

t = linspace (0,5*Tau,100); %100 amostras de 0 a 5*Tau segundos

figure (1)
hold on
% carga do capacitor
plot (t,E*(1-exp(-t/(R*C))),'b-')

% descarga do capacitor
%figure (2)  %para graficos separados descomente essa linha
plot (t,E*(exp(-t/(R*C))),'r-')
```